# ValueForKeyPath is not work how to fix it?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Animal class definition:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *food;
```

Cat class definition:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSData *birthday;
@property (nonatomic, strong) Animal *animal;
```

in main.m file:

```
[cat setValue:@"fish" forKeyPath:@"animal.food"];
NSLog(@"cat eat: %@", [cat valueForKeyPath:@"animal.food"]);
```

Result:

```
2016-01-16 19:31:33.811 Usage of KVC and KVO[6802:201576] cat eat: (null)
```

Why do I get `null`?

Comment: have you initialised `cat`?

Comment: And `cat.animal`? Also, you should probably read about inheritance. You want `Cat` to be a subclass of `Animal` rather than than have it contain an `animal` property?

Comment: Thanks 
I've found the problem.  and add following code can be solved.

    [cat setValue:[[Animal alloc]init] forKeyPath:@"animal"];

Answer (score 1):

Thanks 
I've found the problem.add following code can be sovled.  :)

```
[cat setValue:[[Animal alloc]init] forKeyPath:@"animal"];
```